# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource (AWS, API Gateway, S3, CORS)

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to upload an image file on to my S3 bucket using API Gateway SDK.
However I keep getting the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://*****.execute-api.*****.amazonaws.com/dev/upload/photophotobucket/me.png' from origin 'http://photofront.s3-website-*****.amazonaws.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Below is my javascript code that is initiated when clicking on upload:

```
var apigClient = apigClientFactory.newClient();

function UploadFile() {
    var filePath = document.getElementById('file_path').value //C:\fakepath\me.png
    var file = document.getElementById('file_path').files[0]
    var reader = new FileReader()
    document.getElementById('file_path').value = ""
    if ((filePath == "") || (!['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg'].includes(filePath.split(".")[1]))) {
      alert("WRONG FILE!! Please upload a valid PNG or JPG file")
    } else {
      var params = {
        bucket: 'photophotobucket',
        key: filePath.split("\\").slice(-1)[0], // "me.png"
        'Content-Type': file.type
      };
      var body = {}
      var additionalParams = {
        headers: {
          'x-api-key': 'MYAPIKEY',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS,PUT'
        },
        queryParams: {}
      };
      reader.onload = function (event) {
        body = btoa(event.target.result)
        console.log("body")
        console.log(body)
        var whatToReturn = apigClient.uploadBucketKeyPut(params, body, additionalParams)
          .then(function (result) {
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
          });
        return whatToReturn
      }
      reader.readAsBinaryString(file)
    }
  }
```

I have enabled CORS on my API Gateway for the PUT method. (Everything got check marked).
I tried with and without the `Access-Control-Allow` headers, they both don't work.
What am I missing?

On the API Gateway Console, I already set up "Response Headers for 200". I already do have Integration Response Header Mapping set up with '*'

If there are any other information that you need please ask.

Comment: `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` is a header set on the *response*.  You can't set it on a request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message calls out that it's the Preflight request (aka, the Options method on your resource) that doesn't have the correct Access-Control-Allow-Origin settings.  If you select the Options method and edit the Method Response > Response Headers, you should have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` listed.  The next step is setting a value for it.  Edit the Integration Response > Header Mappings > Access-Control-Allow-Origin and set the value to `'*'` (with single quotes).  This makes it wide open during your troubleshooting, and you can change the value later to be more specific like `'https://example.com'`.

You may get subsequent errors after this step with the *PUT* method call saying the same thing.  You can take these same steps for the Put Method (Adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to the Method Response & and `'*'` to the Integration Response).

Comment: 1. I already set up "Response Headers for 200" 2. I already do have Integration Response Header Mapping set up with '*'

Comment: And just to clarify, you've double checked these headers/values on the _OPTIONS_ method within APIGW correct?  Your description mentions enabling it on the _PUT_ method.  True, APIGW will create the Options method for you when enabling CORS, but doesn't always set the values correctly if not done a certain way.  The error message seems to be very specific as to the cause of the error (Preflight aka Options). _ And you've deployed your API to the correct stage (/dev in your example) after updating?_  To help narrow down the error, if you disable CORS does it allow you to upload the file?

Comment: One other thought...It's possible that the request is erroring out and getting transferred to one of the default APIGW Responses, and that's where the CORS issue is occurring.  In the APIGW Console, if you click on the Gateway Responses and edit the headers for Default 4xx/5xx and add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:'*'` to those, it might help bring the real issue to light.

Comment: Turns out it was just one line error ```Content-Type``` has to go to the ```header```. Thanks anyways!